# How do I use transparent textures in panda3d?

Tags: textures, transparency, panda3d

I need to map a partially transparent texture on a flat quad with panda3d. With the quad as a canvas I'd like to create something like sprites positioned in the 3d coordinate system.

[image: isometric tree]

I wanted to render a tree. As you can see the color values of the trees border have been stretched over the texture. How can I change the texture mode to include the alpha channel ?

I just don't know how to get hold of the right settings. A link to the right manpage would be perfect. If you need more information about the setup you might want to look at my other question: [How do I use setFilmSize in panda3d to achieve the correct view?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22643/problem-with-isometric-rendering)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ThomasEgi on the panda3d irc channel solved the problem. It's actually embarrassingly simple. You need to call

```
thenodePath.setTransparency(True)
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually there are multiple transparency modes:

```
np.setTransparency(TransparencyAttrib.MAlpha)
np.setTransparency(TransparencyAttrib.MDual)
np.setTransparency(TransparencyAttrib.MBinary)
```

The manual explains these stuff.